# How to get a fixed width button with an input field taking the rest of the available space fluidly

Tags: css

Is it possible in CSS only to accomplish to get a input field and button vertically aligned like in my pen:

http://codepen.io/rpkoller/pen/BhKbp/

and then manage that the button aligned to the right has a fixed width and margin to the left to the input field and that the input field is filling the rest of the space fluidly.

Getting the button to the right might work with a float but with that solution the button isn't vertical aligned in the middle anymore. :( and getting the input field fill the remaining space i haven't managed at all. :/

Best regards Ralf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use specifity of floatting element and layout of block elements .

`<button>` first in the flow, floatting before a block wrapping the input. wrapper at `overflow:hidden` and `<input/>` at `width:100%;`.

see test : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hdiyq

Comment: Elegant solution! I have only one problem. I have a few other viewports. In my smallest when no grid is applied yet the input field and the button are aligned under each other as block level elements. In your solution you have exchanged the position of the input and button element in the html markup. In all other viewports i am able to adjust to your solution but in that particular case i doubt i am able to. :(

Comment: you can use a mediaquerie , a floatting pseudo element and clear to drop the buttom under the input area http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HzCet/ , or use `display: flex;` `flex-direction` and `order` : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AyinL/

Comment: Cool! i was kind of head blocked on this one. Thanks that does the trick